# 403 forbidden in google apps activity API v1

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

We are trying to use the Google Apps Activity API to find the changes made to a file in Google drive. We are able to successfully access the google drive API , but the Activity API is throwing 403 forbidden error.

ERROR:

> Message: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Forbidden [403] Errors [
>     Message[Forbidden] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global] ] 
>   InnerException: Stacktrace:    at
>   Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in
>   c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\test\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line
>   102    at
>   WorkPort.Business.Google.DriveRepo.d__11.MoveNext()

Any inputs would be of great help. I am not able to find much documentation on this.

UPDATE:

I have posted my authentication code below.

```
  private static async Task<AuthorizationCodeWebApp.AuthResult> GetCredentials(string userId)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\GoogleApi\\Logs\\customlog.txt", "Inside GetCredentials" + Environment.NewLine);
        try
        {             


            ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
                ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET
            };

            IDataStore credentialPersistanceStore = getPersistentCredentialStore();

            IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = secrets,
                    DataStore = credentialPersistanceStore,
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, AppsactivityService.Scope.Activity,DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly}
                });
            var redirectUri = "https://mwpsi.cognizant.com/GoogleUI";
            var state = "https://mwpsi.cognizant.com/GoogleUI";

            return new AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, redirectUri, state).AuthorizeAsync(userId, CancellationToken.None).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\GoogleApi\\Logs\\customlog.txt", "Error in Getcredentials : " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            throw ex;
        }

 private static IDataStore getPersistentCredentialStore()
        {
            string folderpath = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google.WorkPortApp.CredentialPath"]);
            // TODO: This uses a local file store to cache credentials. You should replace this with
            // the appropriate IDataStore for your application.
            return new FileDataStore(folderpath, true);
        }
```

Get credentials called in the below code before calling activity api.

```
 var resultcreds = await GetCredentials(token);
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\GoogleApi\\Logs\\customlog.txt", "Got credentials "+resultcreds.Credential.UserId + Environment.NewLine);
            if (resultcreds.RedirectUri == null)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\GoogleApi\\Logs\\customlog.txt", "No Redirect Uri" + Environment.NewLine);
                var driveservice = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    ApplicationName = APP_USER_AGENT,
                    HttpClientInitializer = resultcreds.Credential
                });
                AboutResource abtResource = driveservice.About;
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\GoogleApi\\Logs\\customlog.txt", "About Resource: " + abtResource + Environment.NewLine);
                var service = new AppsactivityService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    ApplicationName = APP_USER_AGENT,
                    HttpClientInitializer = resultcreds.Credential
                });
                // Define parameters of request.

                ActivitiesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Activities.List();
                listRequest.Source = "drive.google.com";

                listRequest.DriveAncestorId = "root";
                listRequest.PageSize = 10;
               // listRequest.DriveFileId = fileId;
               // listRequest.UserId = "me";

                // List activities.
                ListActivitiesResponse LAresponse = listRequest.Execute();
                activities = LAresponse.Activities;
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\GoogleApi\\Logs\\customlog.txt", "Got ActivityFeed " + Environment.NewLine);

            }
```

Comment: forbidden normally means you don't have access.  what does your authentication look like what scopes are you requesting?

Comment: I have used oauth.. and the scopes are DriveService.Scope.Drive, AppsactivityService.Scope.Activity,DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly

Comment: and you enabled Apps Activity API  in google developer console?

Comment: yes i have done that, and i am abkle to access the drive api. that means there should not be a problem with oauth right?

Comment: post your authentication code maybe someone else can help.  I am out of ideas sorry

Comment: I have posted the complete code above

Comment: Are the drive files you're making changes to public, or do you have the proper permissions to edit them?

Comment: yes they are public, and i am able to access the activities from javascript api. I face 403 only when i access from dot net code.